# Does $u^TQu\le u^TPu \rightarrow \lambda_{\text{max}}(P^{-1}Q)\le 1$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $P$ and $Q$ are two (either symmetric and positive definite, or arbitrary) matrices and $u^TQu\le u^TPu$ for all $u$, does that mean that the eigenvalues of $P^{-1}Q$ have $1$ as upper bound? How can that be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $P^{-1} Q$ with eigenvector $u$.  Then 
 $Qu = \lambda Pu$.  Premultiply both sides by $u^T$, and you get
$u^T Q u = \lambda u^T P u$.  So if $P$ is positive definite, then $\lambda \le 1$.  (You need the positive definite so that you divide by a positive number.)